# why is the MSE error higher than MASE and MAPE?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, mse, mape, mase

I have a product price time series when I apply two models on them, I calculate all of MSE (Mean Squared Error), MASE (Mean Absolute Scaled Error), and MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error). I noticed that for method 1, the MASE and MAPE are larger than MASE and MAPE for method 2. However, the MSE is smaller than MASE for method 1.

Why is the MSE higher than MASE and MAPE?

Any suggestions? or recommendations? What is the best metric for evaluating the forecast?

Comment: Since the various statistics are expressed in *different units of measurement,* it makes no sense even to compare all three.

Comment: which one is the best to consider it as an official metric? to check which method do better than the other one

Comment: "Official" according to whom?  In what sense of "do better"?  (Consider re-reading Stephan Kolassa's answer below.)

Answer (score 3):

MSE, MAPE and MASE are different functionals of the (probably implicit) predictive density. Different point forecasting algorithms often differ in their ranks according to the different KPIs.

> what is the best metric for evaluating the forecast?

That depends heavily on what you want to do with your forecast, i.e., what decision you base on it. Usually, none of these measures are "best".

If you want an unbiased forecast, MSE is probably least bad.

Comment: Thanks.
But is this different when I am talking about error function that they applied on the test set of the predictions for two methods, since I don't talk about the accurcy metric of the model.

Comment: No, it's not different. Everything I write applies to evaluations on the test set.

Comment: you mean each of these metrics has its own representation. To try to check the best model it depends on what I am searching for is it the actual error for each sample or for the shape of the overall predictions. Right?

Comment: I think that you are right. (I don't know whether I understand you completely.)